# Vba fail to name cell in macro

Tags: excel, vba

I try to name cells with a macro in Excel. Here is the code :

```
Sub setHeader()

    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Cell As Range

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim l As Integer
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0
    l = 0

    Dim MyColumnRange As Range
    Dim MyRowRange As Range
    Dim MyCellRange As Range
    Set MyColumnRange = ActiveSheet.Range("E7:V8")
    Set MyRowRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B10:B16")
    Set MyCellRange = ActiveSheet.Range("E10:V16")

    Dim MyColumnName As String
    Dim MyRowName As String
    Dim MyCellName As String
    MyColumnName = "HC_"
    MyRowName = "HL_"
    MyCellName = "?"

    For Each Cell In MyRowRange
        Cell.Name = MyRowName + CStr(j)
        j = j + 1
    Next Cell

    For Each Cell In MyColumnRange
         If Not IsEmpty(Cell.Value) Then
        Cell.Name = MyColumnName + CStr(i)
        i = i + 1
        End If
    Next Cell

    For Each Cell In MyCellRange
           Cell.Name = MyRowName + CStr(k) + MyCellName + MyColumnName + CStr(l)
             If l = (MyCellRange.Columns.Count - 1) Then
                l = 0
                k = k + 1
            Else            
                l = l + 1
            End If   
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

I works well for the naming in `MyColumnRange` and `MyCellRange`, but for `MyRowRange` I have the error

> "method name of object range failed"

and I do not understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are naming cells in MyRowRange:

```
For Each Cell In MyRowRange
    Cell.Name = MyRowName + CStr(i)
    j = j + 1
Next Cell
```

You are naming them with your terribly named variable `i` but you are incrementing terribly named variable `j`. Probably you mean `Cell.Name = MyRowName + Cstr(j)`

Comment: Does that fix the error or is still throwing "Method name of object range failed"?

Comment: I just ran the code as-is on a blank sheet and had no problem. It appears to be 100% correct.

Comment: I do not have the problem anymore, and I am not sure why. Maybe I always used CStr(i) instead of CStr(j). As cells can not have the same name, it could explain why cells would not be named (but in that case the first cell to be named should have had a name no?). Thanks to all of you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

so, you don't really need to convert to string, try using & instead of + like this example :

```
For j = 1 to MyRowRange.cells.count
    MyRowRange.cells(j).Name = MyRowName & j
Next j
```

i changed your for each loop (wich is fine), just for an example of an other way to do it...